# How to run code when a process is started? c#

Tags: c#

How would I execute code in a C# application when a process (of any type) is launched on the system?

For example, if I started notepad.exe - I would be able to get the path, "C:\Windows\notepad.exe".

Comment: Please explain more with an Example to make it Clear.

Comment: You mean like a Virus scanner scanning the file before Execution? Or something like logging each and every programm start, even if they do not log anything? | This sounds a lot like a XY Problem so a complete picture would help.

Comment: If you're interested just in windowed processes, you could use UI Automation. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55960110/7444103) (it talks about *Forms*, but it will detect the creation of any Window type, console included). If you're interested in the creation of any process type, you can use a [ManagementEventWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementeventwatcher), something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54298316/7444103) (of course, the WMI class will be `Win32_Process`, not `Win32_DiskDrive` as shown there)

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. You said *Is there a way to run code when any process is launched on the system in c#?" Do you mean you want code, written in C#, that will run whenever a process is started? Or do you mean you want code that will run whenever a C# process is started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in managed code no - you can invoke into the Win32 API using something like:

[Hook ZwCreateSection(), CreateProcess() and CreateProcessEx() using mhook to block certain application from launching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50966351/hook-zwcreatesection-createprocess-and-createprocessex-using-mhook-to-blo)
or

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/11985/hooking-the-native-api-and-controlling-process-cre

technically from C#, but your going to have to use windows api functions as there is no .Net equivalent.

You can however iterate currently running processes using the **Process** class, so if you don't care about missing short-lived processes you could just do that on a timer?